# JQuery open new window

Tags: jquery

I have the following embedded inside my jsp. The intention is to open a new JSP with the options specified. But the window does not open when the page loads.

Am I doing something wrong?

thanks

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            var siteId = getUrlVars()[PARAMS.GENERAL.SITEID];
            var options = "channelmode=" + 1 +
            ",resizable=" + 1 +
            ",menubar=" + 0 + 
            ",toolbar=" + 0 + 
            ",location=" + 0 + 
            ",titlebar=" + 1 +
            ",status=" + 1 +
            ",scrollbars=" + 1;

            var name = "reporting";
            var appURL = "t.htm?" PARAMS.GENERAL.SITEID + "=" + siteId;
            window.open(appURL,name,options);
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure your browser is not blocking the new window?

Comment: Are you want to open window or new tab?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open(appURL,name,options,target="_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a '+' missing on line `var appURL = "t.htm?" + PARAMS.GENERAL.SITEID + "=" + siteId;`

```
     <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function() {
                var siteId = getUrlVars()[PARAMS.GENERAL.SITEID];
                var options = "channelmode=" + 1 +
                ",resizable=" + 1 +
                ",menubar=" + 0 + 
                ",toolbar=" + 0 + 
                ",location=" + 0 + 
                ",titlebar=" + 1 +
                ",status=" + 1 +
                ",scrollbars=" + 1;

                var name = "reporting";
                var appURL = "t.htm?" + PARAMS.GENERAL.SITEID + "=" + siteId;
                window.open(appURL,name,options);
            });

        </script>
```